# Index Management - Catalog Category Flat Data - Stuck on processing

Tags: indexing, reindex, indexer, flat-catalog, flat-indexer

The Catalog Category Flat Data has been now stuck for weeks and i can't seem to fix it.

I tried to change the corresponding table in the database:

```
TRUNCAT catalog_product_flat_1, catalog_product_flat_2, etc...
```

I tried to run the indexer manually:

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php'); 
$app = Mage::app('admin');
$indexer = 5;
{
     $reindexProcess = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load($indexer);
     $reindexProcess->reindexAll();
}  
echo "Done!";
?>
```

I tried to run the indexer with shell:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
error_reporting(0);
require_once('app/Mage.php'); 
umask(0);
$indexer="/shell/indexer.php";
if(file_exists($indexer))
{
        $idxlist=array("catalog_product_flat");
        foreach($idxlist as $idx)
        {
            echo "reindex $idx n ";
            exec("php shell/indexer.php --reindex $idx");
        }
}
echo "Done!";
?>
```

I tried deleting the lock files in /var/locks/ but they are being created automatically every hour or so:

```
index_process_1.lock
index_process_2.lock
index_process_3.lock
index_process_4.lock
index_process_10.lock
index_process_11.lock
index_process_5.lock
index_process_6.lock
index_process_7.lock
index_process_8.lock
index_process_9.lock
```

I also tried rebooting the server and apache.

I even checked if the table engine is InnoDB or not by using:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS
```

But really nothing seems to help. I can't even change the status of the category flat data in the magento backend -> configuration, because it is grayed out.

Do you guys know of any suggestions/solutions to this issue?

Comment: when you try to reindex does the process finish successfully? do you see the "Done!" message?

Comment: @alex.ayg, no it shows a blank screen without any errors or messages. It seems as if Magento doesn't respond to reindex process of indexer 5. Because if i change 5 to any other indexer, it works fine.

Comment: Before truncating those tables, be sure to set `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;` before the TRUNCATE command and `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;` after.

Comment: I did TRUNCAT on those tables on a test environment where everything was functioning well and there everything went fine.

TRUNCATE catalog_product_flat_1, catalog_product_flat_2, etc...
Going to Index Management and reindexing the Catalog Category Flat data
Viewing those tables back in database and the table is full again



But as i said that worked like that in a test environment with all the indexers working. But in my production environment somehow the specific indexer is stuck somewhere. This is really strange, something i haven't experienced before.